# How to set cache control headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How do I go about setting the cache control headers for specific files on my web server?  I'm running a LAMP environment.  I don't want to set the cache control sitewide, just for a few files. I am using CloudFront to distribute content from one of my domains. There is no S3 tie-in here. By default, content expires after 24 hours, which is fine for most of the data on the website, however, there are a few pages that I'd like to have only a 1 hour cache limit on.

Comment: I've reread your question and replaced the tutorials with (hopefully) better ones regarding your problems; I'm sure there are significantly better ones available still, but these should be easy to find once you are more into the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) (mostly) obeys the regular HTTP cache control mechanism (see [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)) as documented in [Amazon CloudFront Object Expiration](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html), specifically:

> You can specify a longer expiration time by using the Cache-Control,
>   Pragma, or Expires header **on the object in the origin server**. [...]
>   CloudFront does not restrict their maximum values.
>
> The minimum expiration time you can specify is one hour. If you
>   specify a minimum time of less than one hour, CloudFront uses one
>   hour.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Thus you will have to orchestrate your LAMP stack to apply the desired `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` header specifically to those objects/pages, which will be picked up automatically by CloudFront during its origin fetch thereafter.

How this is done in particular depends on the tools/technologies used to serve the content of course, e.g.:

- Apache - a good tutorial with several example configurations and tips on how to do that with Apache seems to be [How to enable file caching with .htaccess in Apache](http://tutorialpedia.org/tutorials/Apache+enable+file+caching+with+htaccess.html)
- PHP - a concise tutorial featuring a good example for PHP in particular seems to be [HTTP Caching](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/http-caching.html)

For an excellent overview about caching in general I recommend Mark Nottingham's [Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, the answer above is still correct but slightly out of date in one respect, as Cloudfront now supports a minimum TTL of 0.

Amazon Developer Guide: Expiration[1](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)